# STL Pass iterators vs containers

Tags: c++, stl

If I am writing a library function which needs to take in several containers, which is better?

```
template <class Iterator1, class Iterator2>
void func_iterators(Iterator1 first1, Iterator1 last1, Iterator2 first2, Iterator2 last2)
```

or

```
template <class Container1, class Container2>
void func_containers(const Container1 &c1, const Container2 &c2)
```

Comment: Better with respect to what?

Comment: Follow STL algorithms and use iterators. The original justification is that iterators decouple container policy from access policy, leading to `m + n` instead of `m * n` functions for `m` algorithms over `n` containers. Avoid iterators only if you have a compelling reason -- for example, iterators cached by the function may get invalidated between calls, or multi-threaded write access that may invalidate the passed iterators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use the iterator form, then do.  That allows the caller more flexibility - for example, they can pass reverse iterators, or some special purpose iterators that send values elsewhere, perform locking or whatever's needed.  If you need more than just iterator access though - for example, to call `.size()` - passing the `Container` may be a better choice.

Comment: Or simply pass iterators that don't cover the whole container.

Comment: Why would you need `.size()` ? Often it's sufficient to use `end-begin`. That won't work for `list`, of course, but that's why I wondered why `size()` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably more of a style choice than anything.  The STL itself tends to do the first, as it gives the flexibility of which order the iterator is running, as well as whether to do the entire container.  So it depends on what you want your library to do.

Simple solution:

If the library works on a range of elements, go with number one (iterators)

If the library works on a container, go with number two (the container)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the first, for several reasons

1. You can pass restricted ranges, to iterate over only part of the container
2. You can use iterator adaptors, such as `std::reverse_iterator` to go backwards through a container
3. You can operate on things which aren't containers, but have iterator-like behaviour, such as pointers to a C array, or a `std::ostream_iterator`.
4. Better interaction with the standard library -- many functions return iterators, which could in turn be used as arguments to your function.

The downside, of course, is that

```
my_func(v.begin(), v.end(), u.begin(), u.end());
```

is somewhat uglier than calling

```
my_func(v, u);
```

but I think that's just something we have to live with in a Concept-less C++ world.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely take iterators if you can.

Using the iterator form allows for things like passing reverse iterators (rbegin() and rend()). It allow for limited sections to be passed and may also allow for unexpected but nifty application of things like stream iterators. Passing straight containers is probably only sensible if you need container functionality such as the ability to insert/push_back/other.

And of course there is nothing stopping you provide a second overloaded function that takes container types and then calls the iterator version with begin/end, that allowing more concise use if applicable.